# How can I get AD FS Logs using C#

Tags: c#, adfs

There's a little question about getting the AD FS logs. I've gotta create a little **.net C#** program that will grab all the AD FS logs. I've already created a simple log grabber with **C#**, which is grabbing the 3 types of logs(***Security, System and Application***). Can anyone help me with the creation of this little C# program ?
Thanks beforehand for your attention and help :)

Comment: What do you want ? What have you done already ? Show code, be more specific !

Comment: What is AD FS? What does this question have to do with ASP.Net?

Comment: sounds like you need to do some more work on your end.. we are not going to write code for you but we can help in regards to errors efficiency etc.. show what you have done thus far please

Comment: I think @mybirthname , you haven't read the post correctly. I've already said what I've done, and what I want. If there's no code at all, then what should I show you ?
And I don't want you to write a code for me. I just want a little help. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I read really carefully, but SO is not code generation tool. You have the luck that icemanind, share some code with you !

Comment: Whatever pal. Thank you too for your not helpful answer.

Comment: AD FS is the official shorthand  for the much better tag adfs. It stands for Active directory Federation Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AD FS Logs log to the system event viewer logs. This code should help you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace AdfsEventLog
{
    class Program
    {
        class AdfsAuditEventLogListener
        {
            private EventLogWatcher watcher;

            public AdfsAuditEventLogListener(string logName, string query)
            {
                var events = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(
                    handler => this.watcher.EventRecordWritten += handler,
                    handler => this.watcher.EventRecordWritten -= handler);

                this.watcher = new EventLogWatcher(new EventLogQuery(logName, PathType.LogName, query));
                var pairs = events
                              .Where(e299 => e299.EventArgs.EventRecord.Id == 299)
                              .SelectMany(e299 => events.Where(e500 => e500.EventArgs.EventRecord.Id == 500 &&
                                                                       e299.EventArgs.EventRecord.Properties[0].Value.ToString() ==
                                                                       e500.EventArgs.EventRecord.Properties[0].Value.ToString())
                                                        .Take(1),
                                         (e299, e500) => new { First = e299, Second = e500 });


                pairs.Subscribe(r =>
                {
                    this.SuccessEventsWritten(this, new SuccessEventsWrittenEventArgs { Logs = new List<EventRecord>(new[] { r.First.EventArgs.EventRecord, r.Second.EventArgs.EventRecord }) });
                });
            }

            public event EventHandler<SuccessEventsWrittenEventArgs> SuccessEventsWritten;

            public void Start()
            {
                this.watcher.Enabled = true;
            }

            public void Stop()
            {
                this.watcher.Enabled = false;
            }

        }

        class SuccessEventsWrittenEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public IList<EventRecord> Logs { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listener = new AdfsAuditEventLogListener("Security", "*[System[(EventID=500 or EventID=299)]]");
            listener.SuccessEventsWritten += (sender, arg) =>
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;

                var e299 = arg.Logs.SingleOrDefault(@event => @event.Id == 299);
                var e500 = arg.Logs.SingleOrDefault(@event => @event.Id == 500);

                Console.WriteLine("Claims for: {0} (Correlation: {1})", e299.Properties[1].Value.ToString(), e299.Properties[0].Value.ToString());

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", string.Join("\n\t", e500.Properties
                                                                .Skip(1)
                                                                .Where(e => e.Value.ToString() != "-")
                                                                .PairUp()
                                                                .Select(t => t.Item1.Value.ToString() + " : " + t.Item2.Value.ToString())
                                                                .ToArray()));
            };

            listener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            listener.Stop();
        }
    }

    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> PairUp<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var first = iterator.Current;
                    var second = iterator.MoveNext() ? iterator.Current : default(T);
                    yield return Tuple.Create(first, second);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have +1 for the effort !